# What is the domain and co-domain of this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $R = \{(1,2)(1,1),(1,3),(3,2),(2,3)\}$ what is the domain and codomain of $R$?

In class, the professor did not give a clear definition and straight-forward example of what domain and co-domain mean. This is a discrete math class I'm asking for.

EDIT: R is a relation on G, where G is {1,2,3}

Comment: Typically domains and codomains are associated with functions, and you have R defined as a set. Are you sure you have all the information to this problem?  Note that domains and codomains are themselves sets.

Comment: Yes, typically domain and codomain are terms used in the context of functions, but functions are special kinds of relations, and when you have a 1-place function written as a (2-place, i.e. Binary) relation! You can consider the 'left' elements the domain and the 'right' elements the codomain.  Note that we typically also make a distinction between codomain and range, but in this example those two would coincide. See the Wikipedia article on Binary relations.

Answer (score 1):

The domain is probably meant to be the set of objects that are the possible first elements of the pairs in $R$, and the co-domain the set of objects that are the possible second elements of the pairs in $R$. So, since you have a 1, 2, and 3 as possible first (or 'left') elements, the domain is $\{ 1,2,3\}$. Same for the dodomain.

Comment: I edited the question above.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this relation with you, now the set of first elements of all the ordered pairs is called the domain, whereas the set of the second elements of the ordered pairs is called the range.
In a relation from A to B, the entire set B is called the co-domain. It's basically the entire values of what can come out as an answer,whereas R is what came out as an answer.
One important thing here is that R is a subset of the Co-domain.
Refer to the example below
A={1,2,3,4} and B={5,6,7,8}
R={(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)}
Domain={1,2,3}
Range={5,6,7}
Co-domain={5,6,7,8}=Set B